# ons-toolbarに画像を埋め込む

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

ons-toolbarに画像を埋め込みたいのですがどのようにすれば埋め込めますでしょうか？
ご存知の方はご教授の程、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

background-image:url('url')をdivタグに入れる方法はどうでしょうか。

```
    <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center" style="background-image:url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/ja/img/sprites.png?v=b55eefad6ab0')"></div>
    <div class="right">
      <ons-toolbar-button>
        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em">
      </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
  </ons-toolbar>
```

Comment: user7461様 回答して頂きまして有り難うございます。
まさにやりたかった事です！！
<ons-toolbar style="background-image:url()">とやっていた為、全く表示されていなかった様です。 どうも有り難うございました♪

Comment: 質問を解決済に変更してくれると有難いです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`modifier` 属性を併用してカスタマイズもできます。

```
<ons-toolbar modifier="hogehoge">
  <div class="center">Center Area</div>
</ons-toolbar>
```

CSSでは、 `ons-toolbar` の場合 `navigation-bar--(modifier属性値)`のクラスを指定します。

```
.navigation-bar--hogehoge {
  background:url('http://placehold.jp/150x50.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```